# How to unlock the Monument of Leonidas

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I have an objective to build the monument of Leonidas but I can't find how to unlock it. I didn't find it in any of the technologies.

So how can I unlock it to build it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's the 5th stage Recruitment building for Spartans.

**More Specifically**

> Encyclopedia ----> Buildings ----> Hellenistic---> Military Scroll
>   Scroll down to Sparta Tier 5 barracks, after royal barracks

**Screenshot** 
[image: Monument of Leonidas]

**Note**

> All high ranking building can only be built in capitals

**Source**
[Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/214950/discussions/0/864978762506825966/)
[Total War Forums](http://forums.totalwar.com/showthread.php/98269-Where-s-the-Monument-of-Leonidas)